# Javascript explain the use of 'this'

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and trying to understand why javascript uses `this.vanilla`.

Is this the same as writing:

```
var SomeVariable = [1, "bean", vanilla ? vanilla : "Madagascar Bourbon"];
```

Seems very confusing using same name as the parameter `vanilla`.

```
var VanillaBean = function(vanilla, cinnamon) {
    this.vanilla = [1, "bean", vanilla ? vanilla : "Madagascar Bourbon"];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried searching "this javascript" in Google?

Comment: This is very small question for very large problem. You should try some cases to undestand problem. None article give you simply answer for this issue.

Comment: That depends on how `VanillaBean` is called, but probably it is called with `new`, i.e. as a [constructor function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function). This might also be helpful: [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)

Comment: `this` is a core part of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `VanillaBean` is a function which accepts two arguments called `vanilla` and `cinnamon`. It will create an object with at least one property, `vanilla` when invoked like below:

```
var flavour = new VanillaBean("cheap", 250);
```

`flavour.vanilla` will then be `[1, "bean", "cheap"]`.

(Thanks @FelixKling and @t.niese.)

`this` refers to the object it creates, and not some other `vanilla` property of anything else.

If you were to use the first version involving `SomeVariable` you would still get a list, but it would only be a standalone variable, not a property of any object (well, `window`, probably, but...)

Comment: Better :) You should mention that the function has to be invoked with the `new` operator, otherwise it won't create a new object.

Comment: @FelixKling @icedwater **invoked** could mean `VanillaBean(...)`, `VanillaBean.call(somObj, ...)` and `new VanillaBean(...)` or am I wrong there? If so it will only create an object if invoked with `new`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = {};
```

`this` in object:

```
a.test = function () { return this; };
```

In this case `this` will be `a` because `function` is member of a.

```
a.t = function () {
  var b = function () { return this; };
  b();
};
```

In this case `b` is not member of anything so `this` is `window`.

To understand `this` just check who own function and if it don't have any owner it represent window. Every function without owner is automatically owned by window.

Additional you can change temporarily owner calling.

```
var b = function () {};
var c = { d: 1 };
b.call(c);
```

Call function temporarily change owner to `c` and `this` will be `c`.

Creating new instance.

```
function E() { this.h = 2; }
E.prototype = { f: 1 };
E.prototype.g = function () { return this; };
var e = new E();
e.g();
```

In this case `this` is `e`. `prototype` is  structure that give you possibility to describe how new object will be initially looks like. Here it will be `{ h: 2, g: func, f: 1 }`.

Comment: Did you check what `var b = function () { return this; };` returns, when you call `b();`?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Usually I don't call unbinded functions.

Answer (score 0):

When used in html elements, `this` refers to the element in the DOM.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function hover(domElement) {
        domElement.style.backgroundColor = '#CCC';
    }
</script>
<div onmouseover="hover(this);">Hover me</div>
```

When `this` is used in a non-returning function, the function becomes an object-constructor, and `this` refers to an implicitly created object that automatically gets returned when the function is invoked with `new`.

Example:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    this.x = x || 0;
    this.y = y || 0;
    this.distance = function (point) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(point.x - this.x, 2) +
            Math.pow(point.y - this.y, 2)
        );
    };
}

var a = new Point(10, 10);
var b = new Point(100, 100);

document.write(a.distance(b));
```

The same function without `this` and `new`:

```
function Point(x, y) {
    obj = {};

    obj.x = x || 0;
    obj.y = y || 0;
    obj.distance = function (point) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            Math.pow(point.x - this.x, 2) +
            Math.pow(point.y - this.y, 2)
        );
    };

    return obj;
}

var a = Point(10, 10);
var b = Point(100, 100);

document.write(a.distance(b));
```